# How to build remote Webdriver for Chrome in python

Tags: python, selenium

I've start the hub and rc,like the below:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role hub

java -jar selenium-standalone-2.21.0.jar -role wd -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register  -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=path-to-chromedriver
```

but when i use code like this:

```
capability =webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://172.16.21.13:4444/wd/hub", capability)
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
```

it fails and the error is:'Error forwarding the new session cannot find : {platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, version=}'

so, who can tell me how to run remote chome correctly,thanks in advance

Comment: What happens when you run it without grid?

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a problem with empty version in desired capabilities.
Try launching with just browserName:
    `driver = webdriver.Remote("http://172.16.21.13:4444/wd/hub", { "browserName": "chrome"})`